# automated way of using decimal but only when number is in millions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following numbers

```
353,200,000
110,000
```

I would like the output to be

```
353.2m
110k
```

Also I would like this formatting to somehow be applied to selected cells quickly in the whole sheet. Thanks

Comment: Not aware of any pre-built formatting to meet that desired format. This would be ugly, but you could create another column with your numbers, but format them as text and make sure to keep your commas. Then create a 3rd column and use a combo formula against the 2nd column, one that looks at the length of the cell, and if more than 6, then do one thing and less than 6 then do another. So the output would indeed show 353.2m, but this would also be a text column and may need several IF's based on how large your numbers get.

Comment: [This may be of use](https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/format-numbers-to-millions-thousands-excel/)

Answer (score 0):

On a general kevel, I believe the closest you can get is a scientific format with exponents set to multiples of three, as in

[image]

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and set cells to e.g. Custom (User defined) format `##0.00E+00`

For ALL cells, select them with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> first.

*NOTE: "m" (lower case m)  is for milli (100E-03 for 100m).*